# Поиск на сайте по имени товара со знаком "+"

Tags: url, поиск, opencart, php

Всем привет. Столкнулся с такой неприятностью в Опенкарте. Есть в интернет магазине товары, имя которых содержит +, например **DEUTER Рюкзак Guide 30+ SL**

Когда вбиваю в поисковую строку полностью это название - браузер принудительно кодирует + в %20, то есть в пробел. В итоге поиск ничего не находит, так как в базе нету товара с именем  DEUTER Рюкзак Guide 30 SL. Если вбить в поиск **Рюкзак Guide 30** (без плюса и остального бреда), то все хорошо находит.

Что посоветуете сделать в данной ситуации?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="search">
     <input type="submit" class="button-search" value="Найти"/>
     <input type="text" id="search" name="filter_name" value="" />                  
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.button-search').bind('click', function() {
    url = $('base').attr('href') + 'index.php?route=product/search';

    var filter_name = $('input[name=\'filter_name\']').attr('value');

    if (filter_name) {
        url += '&filter_name=' + encodeURIComponent(filter_name);
    }

    location = url;
});

$('.search input[name=\'filter_name\']').bind('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        url = $('base').attr('href') + 'index.php?route=product/search';

        var filter_name = $('input[name=\'filter_name\']').attr('value');

        if (filter_name) {
            url += '&filter_name=' + encodeURIComponent(filter_name);
        }

        location = url;
    }
});
```

**PHP:** В модель попадает кодированная то ли браузером, то ли джаваскриптом строка, и при этом пропущенная через htmlspecialchars

```
if (isset($this->request->get['filter_name'])) {
    $filter_name = $this->request->get['filter_name'];
} else {
    $filter_name = '';
}
```

**Код модели:**

```
if (!empty($data['filter_name'])) {                 
    if (!empty($data['filter_description'])) {
        $sql .= "LCASE(pd.name) LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "%' OR MATCH(pd.description) AGAINST('" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "')";
    } else {
        $sql .= "LCASE(pd.name) LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "%'";
    }
}
```

Comment: Приведите клиентский и серверный код, если возможно, который отвечает за кодирование/раскодирование поискового запроса.

Comment: @ReinRaus, обновил ответ

Comment: Либо идет двойное применение функции urlencode к $_GET, что вряд ли могло быть допущено в фреймворке, либо аналогичная функция применяется где-то на уровне .htaccess (а может у меня просто бренд). Приведите .htaccess или поищите в коде фреймворка вхождение слов urldecode или unescape.

Comment: А вообще было бы хорошо видеть значения запроса с которым мы работаем на каждом этапе.  
Перед сменой адреса в браузере, перед началом работы фреймворка, перед передачей в скуль.  
Так можно более точно локализовать источник.

Answer (score 1):

В  JS поисковая строка кодируется

```
encodeURIComponent(filter_name)
```

Для приведения её в исходное состояние в php существует команда urldecode
В модели используйте примерно такую конструкцию:

```
urldecode($data['filter_name'])
```

[urldecode php.net](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urldecode.php)

Comment: понимаете, если в поисковую строку ручками вбить site.ru/index.php?route=product/search&filter_name=DEUTER%20%D0%A0%D1%8E%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%20Guide%2030%2B%20SL (посмотрите, в конце строки есть 30%2B%20SL, то есть кодированная 30+ SL), браузер сам этот плюс превращает в пробел, то есть %2B заменяет на %20. Использовал ваше предложение, даже убирал encodeURIComponent с джаваскрипта - не помогло

Comment: @mountpoint, браузер этого не делает. Он отправляет на сервер %2В. Приведите значения этого параметра ГЕТ на разных этапах работы серверной части кода.